# Firebase set new unique ID

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm new to firebase and practicing creating a ToDo application. So far this is my code:

**Code:**

```
var getUserRef = firebase.database().ref('users');

getUserRef.on('child_added', function(data) {
    var name = data.child("name").val();
    var email = data.child("email").val();
    $('#loadData').append(`<tr><td>${name}</td><td>${email}</td><td>Edit Remove</td></tr>`);
});

function addUser() {
    var database = firebase.database();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var newID = 4; // How can this be incremented?
    database.ref('users/' + newID).set({
        name: name,
        email: email
    });
}
```

**Data Structure:**

[image]

As you can see, everytime I create a new user, I am manually changing the `newID` variable.

My problem is I don't want to change it everytime I insert a new user. I want it to aumotically increment or generate a random unique ID.

Is there a way to do this in google firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is a list of items. If you have such a list, it is common to [use Firebase's `push()` method to add new items to it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data). This will generate a chronological key that is guaranteed to be unique across all clients, even in cases where some clients may have temporarily lost their network connection while they're adding data. These push IDs are not as readable as your array indices, but they are the recommended way of adding items to a list.

That said; you're not dealing with any list here, it is a list of users. If you're using Firebase Authentication to manage the user accounts and handle authentication, the users come with a build in id called `uid`. In such a case it makes more sense to store the items under their natural key, so under their `uid` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is.
Here is a code from firebase docs of an example of Push().

```
var messageListRef = firebase.database().ref('message_list');
var newMessageRef = messageListRef.push();
newMessageRef.set({
  'user_id': 'ada',
  'text': 'Example of text.'
});
```

You can find all this information about other methods here :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference